# Upgrading from IPython 5.x to 6.0 results in crash due to IPython.utils.warn

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I recently upgraded from IPython 5.x to 6.0 via `condo update ipython`.  However, I get a crash in the kernel:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .zmqshell import ZMQInteractiveShell
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.warn import error
ImportError: No module named 'IPython.utils.warn'
[I 18:35:28.928 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
```

Apparently, the issue is that `IPython.utils.warn` was deprecated and [has now been removed](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html) as of version 6.0.0.  How can I fix this?

Note: none of the following worked:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
pip install --upgrade jupyter 
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall ipython
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall jupyter
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. The following line fixed the issue for me:

```
conda update ipykernel
```

I don't know why this is not done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

+1 same problem.

Workaround was to downgrade to the latest available 5.x version of iPython (currently 5.3.0 found via `conda search ipython`):

```
conda install ipython=5.3.0
```

Now Jupyter notebook kernel can start again.